# Sliding Text In a Label

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uilabel

In my Xcode Project I have a tableview that is populated with a label. Sometimes the text in the label does not fit all the way causing the label to cut off the rest of the text. So I will like to add in a sliding effect in the label where it will show the beginning text and then start to slide all the way to the end of the string and back **only when the user is not scrolling in the tableview**. How will I implement this?

Comment: https://github.com/cbpowell/MarqueeLabel

Comment: If you have dynamic size `UITableviewCell` it would automatically adjust height of cell based on content of `UILabel`, you just need to make sure to assign appropriate constraints. I believe you don't need scrolling. If your cell has only label then assign (top, left, bottom, right) constraint to cell superview.

Comment: You need to set number of lines = 0

Answer (score 0):

Just assign the leading, trailing, top, bottom constrains of this label = 0 with the cell itself and let the tableView to calculate each cell's size dynamically